# Actions dropdown too far right in Admin Listing

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, drop-downs, action, product-listing

I've managed to add a second action to the actions column in the admin product listing. It works fine until I add another column to the display. The dropdown menu doesn't "follow" the actions column and stays on the right :
[image]

Is there any way to fix this ?
I'm running Magento 2.3.3

EDIT

Here's my code

etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <!-- Plugin that adds an action to the default admin panel product listing -->
  <type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\ProductActions">
    <plugin name="pluginname" type="Vendor\Module\Plugins\AddStatsActionToProductListing" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
  </type>
</config>
```

Plugin Class

```
public function afterPrepareDataSource(\Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\ProductActions $subject, $result)
{

    foreach ($result['data']['items'] as &$item) {
        $item[$subject->getData('name')]['stats'] = [
            'href' => $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl(
                'vendor_module/groups_perproduct/index',
                ['product_id' => $item['entity_id']]
            ),
            'label' => __('Stats'),
            'hidden' => false,
            '__disableTmpl' => true
        ];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Could you update the code?

Comment: @Jimmy  Thanks for asking, I uploaded my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the code, the `Action` column seems be meant to be the last column.

The reason you have this is because the list actions, `<ul>` tag is positioned absolute, whereas the closest relative element is `.admin__data-grid-outer-wrap`, so the `ul`'s position will be aligned with that relative element.

No matter what the last column is, the `ul` will always be there, at that specific position

Comment: Oh I see it makes sense. It's kinda weird that magento makes it possible to add columns to the right of the action's column. I guess the solution would be to have a custom column that replaces the action one, with the same layout ? I believe that's possible.

Comment: you could add as many columns as you want, just position them before Action column to make it displays correctly.